# Tutorial to record audio on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, audio

could anyone explain how to record audio on the iphone. I already read the sampleProject of the developer-page. Moreover the documentation didn't quite answered my question.

It would be great to have a kind of checklist how to implement a simple audiorecorder.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you need in a checklist that's not in the SpeakHere example?

Answer (score 0):

There is already one as a sample app.
Check "Speak Here" that app records and play sounds. Is a low level sample for CoreAudio.Framework

But if you prefer something newer (and probably better for your needs) check for AVFoundation.framework I am sure there are new APIs in iOS 4.0 that allow to capture sounds like AVCapture, AVInputDevice, etc.

Cheers